# Exception when trying to parse string to date with clojure.java-time for a specific function call

Tags: clojure

I have a function that calculates the time diff between two instants:

```
(defn calculate-time-diff [time1 time2]
  (let [parsed-time1 (time/instant time1)
        parsed-time2 (time/instant time2)]
    (time/time-between parsed-time1 parsed-time2 :seconds)))
```

It works fine when called by another function I'd been working with.

But now I'm implementing a validation that should call it as well:

```
(defn doubled-transaction? [merchant amount time transactions]
    (let [similar-transactions (filter (has-values :merchant merchant :amount amount) transactions)
          time-last-similar (:time (first similar-transactions))]
      (< (calculate-time-diff time time-last-similar) 120)))
```

This time, I get a NullPointerException and I can't understand why.

`time-last-similar` (which comes as `time2` into the `calculate-time-diff` function) seems to be the one causing problem. But if I add a `println time2` to the beginning of `calculate-time-diff`, the right value seems to be there. Something like `2019-02-13T10:00:30.000Z`.

But then I can't get it parsed to a date format using time/instant (which works fine for other function calls).

Part of the stack trace:

```
 Class.java:     -2  java.lang.Class/isAssignableFrom
 graph.clj:      61  java-time.graph/assignable-type?
 graph.clj:      60  java-time.graph/assignable-type?
 graph.clj:      71  java-time.graph/fn
 graph.clj:      66  java-time.graph/fn
 util.clj:       50  java-time.potemkin.util/fast-memoize/fn
 graph.clj:     279  java-time.graph/has-source-type?/contains-src-types?/fn
 core.clj:     2701  clojure.core/some
 core.clj:     2692  clojure.core/some
 graph.clj:     279  java-time.graph/has-source-type?/contains-src-types?
 graph.clj:     281  java-time.graph/has-source-type?
 graph.clj:     277  java-time.graph/has-source-type?
 graph.clj:     301  java-time.graph/fn
 graph.clj:     300  java-time.graph/fn
 util.clj:       52  java-time.potemkin.util/fast-memoize/fn
 graph.clj:     316  java-time.graph/conversion-fn
 graph.clj:     312  java-time.graph/conversion-fn
 temporal.clj:  350  java-time.temporal/instant
 temporal.clj:  350  java-time.temporal/instant
 logic.clj:      13  authorizer.logic/calculate-time-diff
```

Comment: Do the line-numbers actually corelate to an problem with `time2`? Also try not just to println, but try prn, or printing the the result of type or bean (anything, that gives more insight into what you are actually getting handed down)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen those stacktraces and NPEs a lot recently when I tried to parse dates from the Jira API.

I ended up checking for `nil`s myself, before passing strings to the time functions and to not rely on automatic parsing:

```
(ns my-example
  (:require
   ;; ...
   [java-time :as t]))

(def jira-time-stamp-format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")

(defn jira-time [s]
  (when s
    (t/local-date-time jira-time-stamp-format s)))
```

Using that function was the only way I could make the whole code less brittle. Still ran into problems calling `t/duration` at times.

I know this is not a precise answer to your question. It's just that it helped me a lot with a similar problem.

Comment: I tried that, but I'm getting a "Text could not be parsed".

Comment: Put a single quote around the `Z` in the formatter. You can probably also find a way to call `local-date-time` with a `:iso-instant` formatter. I didn't find it out quickly, though. My apologies.